# Como mostrar fazer uma espécie de log de atualização enquanto a query está sendo rodada?

Tags: ajax

```
    $("#gerar-senha").on("click", function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "gerar-valores-randomicamente.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#formulario").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                $("#myModal").modal();
                $("#myModal").find("#modal-body").append(data);
            }
        });
    });
```

A minha ideia é abrir um modal e adicionar dentro dela um log de atualização enquanto a `query` está sendo rodada.

Existe alguma coisa função no `ajax` que imprima os dados enquanto a query estiver rodando? com `success` a requisição só aparece quando for bem sucedida.

por exemplo:

```
    $id = "1" ;
    do{
        //faz o update 
        $result = $database->update($query, array(":id",$id));
        $id++;
        echo "coluna ".$id." fez o update com sucesso"; 
    }
    while($id <= "2000");
```

dentro do modal:

---

| coluna 1 fez o update com sucesso;

| coluna 2 fez o update com sucesso;

| verificando // enquanto a query está sendo rodada

| coluna n fez o update com sucesso; //após verificar, mostra-se se foi atualizado ou não

---

Comment: Não. A prática é simples: uma requisição obtém uma resposta. Pra fazer o que você quer, teria que fazer um *loop* no seu JS, chamando o *WS* para fazer um *update* de cada vez.